# Using Jupyter Lab with tmpnb

Tags: proxy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to use [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) using [tmpnb](https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb)

I want to spawn many [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) instances, just like the way [tmpnb](https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb) does for Jupyter Notebook.

I have created a new docker image by `docker build -t jupyterlab2 .` command using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
MAINTAINER apr
RUN pip install npm
RUN pip install jupyterlab
RUN jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab
```

After this I am running the following commands:

```
export TOKEN=$( head -c 30 /dev/urandom | xxd -p )

docker run --net=host -d -e CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN=$TOKEN --name=proxy jupyter/configurable-http-proxy --default-target http://127.0.0.1:9999

docker run --net=host -d -e CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN=$TOKEN --name=tmpnb -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock jupyter/tmpnb python orchestrate.py --allow_origin='*' --image='jupyterlab2' --pool-size=5 --container-user=root  --command='jupyter lab --allow-root LabApp.allow_origin="*"'
```

When I visit the URL `http://<ip-address>:8000`, I get redirected to `http://<ip>:8000/user/sTVKGwH01uoQ`, but this shows 404. 
I also tried visiting `http://<ip>:8000/user/sTVKGwH01uoQ/lab` but this too gives 404.

Logs for 1 instance are below:

```
Set username to: jovyan
usermod: no changes
Set jovyan GID to: 100
Execute the command: jupyter lab --allow-root --port 8888 --ip=0.0.0.0 --LabApp.allow_origin=*
[I 09:05:52.598 LabApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 09:05:54.689 LabApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 09:05:54.694 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 09:05:54.694 LabApp] 0 active kernels
[I 09:05:54.694 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:05:54.694 LabApp] http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=584fc5114d037ad23296ca8284ea1074b220d058018cb2c4
[I 09:05:54.694 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:05:54.695 LabApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=584fc5114d037ad23296ca8284ea1074b220d058018cb2c4
[I 09:05:57.142 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.54ms
[W 09:05:57.144 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 1.45ms referer=None
[I 09:05:57.347 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.56ms
[W 09:05:57.350 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 1.44ms referer=None
[I 09:05:57.553 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.55ms
[W 09:05:57.556 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 1.41ms referer=None
[I 09:05:57.767 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 2.80ms
[W 09:05:57.773 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 3.44ms referer=None
[I 09:05:57.978 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.56ms
[W 09:05:57.981 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 1.46ms referer=None
[I 09:05:58.184 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.55ms
[W 09:05:58.187 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 1.42ms referer=None
[I 09:05:58.391 LabApp] 302 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/ (172.17.0.1) 0.56ms
[W 09:05:58.394 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o (172.17.0.1) 2.05ms referer=None
[W 09:06:18.518 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/tree (172.17.0.1) 1.61ms referer=http://52.71.15.52:8000/
[W 09:06:27.502 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/lab (172.17.0.1) 2.51ms referer=None
[W 09:07:20.568 LabApp] 404 GET /user/1BhE9UZ2gg5o/lab (172.17.0.1) 2.28ms referer=None
```

I looked at [an issue related to JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker/issues/26), which looked very similar. The 404 error page is same for me too. I tried some random things with `start.sh` too, but no luck.

Is it even possible to run JupyterLab using tmpnb? If no, then what are the other tools that I can use the achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The base URL must be set, otherwise the `/user/...` routes won't map to the right things. This is the `--NotebookApp.base_url={base_path}` part in the all of the example commands [in the tmpnb README](https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb#quick-start). These look like:

```
python orchestrate.py --command='jupyter notebook --no-browser \
    --port {port} --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.base_url={base_path} \
    --NotebookApp.port_retries=0'
```

So a JupyterLab equivalent would be:

```
python orchestrate.py --command='jupyter lab --no-browser \
    --port {port} --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.base_url={base_path} \
    --NotebookApp.port_retries=0'
```

All of those apply with jupyterlab as well, so probably the only arg you want to replace is `notebook` with `lab`. At the same time, you don't need to change the default command at all, because if the lab extension is installed, jupyterlab is available at the `/lab` URL when you start `jupyter notebook`. You can see this right now by replacing `/tree` with `/lab` on any existing tmpnb.org URL.

Comment: Thanks! This works actually. I had tried this before as well. 
lab/static/main.bundle.js takes too much time to load for the first time. 
On a slow Internet connection, that got to thinking that it's not working.
As I check, the file is actually ~7.5MB and was not getting delivered with Content-Encoding: gzip